# How to search in jcr:content/@jcr:data using JCR XPath?

Tags: java, xpath, aem, jcr

I would like to search a JCR repository contained in a CQ 5.6 (AEM) instance for all `.jsp` files that contain a given string `xxx`. Being new to JCR's interpretation of XPath (or JCR-SQL2), I'm not quite successful in expressing the query.

This will get me all `.jsp` files:

```
//*[jcr:contains(., '.jsp')]
```

This is how I would expect to restrict the above list of `.jsp` files that contain `xxx`:

```
//*[jcr:contains(., '.jsp')][jcr:contains(jcr:content/@jcr:data, 'xxx')]
//*[jcr:contains(., '.jsp') and jcr:contains(jcr:content/@jcr:data, 'xxx')]
//*[jcr:contains(., '.jsp')]/jcr:content[jcr:contains(@jcr:data, 'xxx')]/..
```

`@jcr:data` being of type `Binary`. None of the above seem to work. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the query should be on the nt:file node, not on the jcr:data node.  See this answer to [JCR - Jackrabbit - Xpath expression for search content text of a file contained inside a node](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11942340/252840).

A quick test using querybuilder shows results coming from JSP files in CQ (in this example where they contain "/foundation/global.jsp"):

```
http://localhost:4502/bin/querybuilder.json?type=nt:file&nodename=*.jsp&group.1_fulltext=foundation/global.jsp
```

gives:

```
{
  success: true,
  results: 10,
  total: 21,
  offset: 0,
  hits: [
    {
      path: "/libs/cq/personalization/components/offerpage/body.jsp",
      excerpt: " --%&gt;&lt;%@include file=&quot;/libs/<strong>foundation/global.jsp</strong>&quot;%&gt;&lt;% I18n i18n = new I18n(slingRequest); String icnCls = ...",
      name: "body.jsp",
      title: "body.jsp",
      lastModified: "2013-04-24 11:45:05",
      created: "2013-04-24 11:32:58",
      size: "3 KB",
      mimeType: "text/plain"
    },
...
}
```

Comment: That's it. The solution is to write `//*[jcr:contains(., '.jsp')][jcr:contains(jcr:content, 'xxx')]`. Not so intuitive, though...

Comment: ... yeah, I hadn't thought of the querybuilder. Nice thinking

Comment: I am trying to run a similar query but searching over JavaScript files, but it doesn't work, it should be the same scenario, but I cannot understand why I get zero results.